# triple integral question

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So given this triple integral of z, the boundaries are graphed out as shown in picture, what i don't understand is what is actually happen conceptually as you are integrating dx, dy, dz one by one. In another words, what is happening graphically (visually) as you go through each level of integration? does z become a line with invisible variables after you complete the dz phase? I want to try to 'see' with my mind, but i am unable to grasp it.[image]

Comment: A way of "visualizing" the several integrations is to think of how you calculate the volume of a cube. First you integrate a long the x-axis to get the length, then for all points on the line you integrate along the y-axis to get a surface. Then for each point on this surface you integrate along the z-axis to get the full volume.

Comment: i understand that, and i get that that would be the case if you were triple integrating over the number 1, but in the case where there is a function (like 'z'), what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, we can think of the integrand $z$ as a "density function." At a particular point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ of the solid $E$, the density is $z_0,$ and so the "differential mass" at that point is $z_0\,dV.$

Now, if the density were some constant--that is, if we were integrating $$\iiint_E\alpha\,dV$$ for some constant $\alpha$--then we can bring the constant out, and the total mass of the solid is simply the density $\alpha$ times the volume. In your particular example, the density isn't constant, so it isn't quite so simple, but you can still think of $$\iiint_E z\,dV$$ as the mass of the solid $E,$ where the density at each point is simply the $z$-coordinate.